# String into JSON Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

In a function, I have to insert a string into a data array, that is part of axios request call:

```
    var obj1 = JSON.parse(payload);

    axios.request({
        url: inUrl,
        method: "POST",
        auth: {
            username: auth,
            password: pass
        },
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        data: {
            "success": inState,
            "fails": inCount,
            obj1
        }
    }).then(res => {
        //console.log(res);
        console.log("bucket commopn response: "+ res.status);
        return "success";
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log("bucket error reponse: " + error.response.status);
        return "error";
    });
```

payload is a pure string with the content:

```
{"branch":"CPL-1223"}
```

This was created from an object with

```
var payload = JSON.stringify(req.body.responsePayload);
```

How can I insert the new object into

```
        data: {
            "success": inState,
            "fails": inCount,
            obj1
        }
```

To make a valid call? Because currently, whatever I do, I get from the Axios server a invalid body, if I make hand call

```
        data: {
            "success": inState,
            "fails": inCount,
            "branch":"CPL-1223"
        }
```

I get a success back. What is my fault?

Comment: Try `...obj1` instead of just `obj1` in data.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your code you're trying to do this:

```
const obj = { branch: 'CPL-1223' }
const body = {
  data: {
    success: '',
    fails: '',
    obj
  }
}
```

If you make a `console.log` on this constant `body` you will get this:

```
{
  data: {
    success: '',
    fails: '',
    obj: {
      branch: 'CPL-1223'
    }
  }
}
```

So the mistake is that you're trying to insert whole object without spreding it. More information about spread syntax you can read here - [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

So to make body like this:

```
{
  data: {
    success: '',
    fails: '',
    branch: 'CPL-1223'
  }
}
```

you should use spread operator `...` and you will get the expected result.

```
const obj = { branch: 'CPL-1223' }
const body = {
  data: {
    success: '',
    fails: '',
    ...obj
  }
}
```

Do not afraid to use `console.log`! It is very powerfull tool that can help you to understand more.

Answer (score 0):

```
    data: {
        "success": inState,
        "fails": inCount,
        obj1
    }
```

In this code snippet you are attaching `obj1` to `data` object as a nested sub object. But your use case is to have the contents of `obj1` to be inserted inside `data` object. For that you can use the new [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`).

You can fix your code by using the below code snippet -

```
    data: {
        "success": inState,
        "fails": inCount,
        ...obj1
    }
```